# "Unable to access page" error while trying to make user inactive

Tags: automation, user-record, recordtriggeredflow

I have created a flow, where - when the user status goes to "inactive" - the contacts who the user oversees are assigned over to another user, who we will call "John Doe". When I am trying to test the flow by making changes to the user status case from "active" to "inactive", I run into the following error. Please advice on this:

> Unable to Access Page The value of a parameter contains a character
> that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length.
> Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value
> length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our
> Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting
> as well as any other related information.

Comment: Is this a record triggered Flow and you make the user inactive by Salesforce's normal administration of users?!

Comment: having run int this error yesterday, for me, there was automation on changing the user (in my case, an after save record-triggered flow) that failed on a step - you should get an email with the flow error if configured to receive such errors

Comment: @FelixvanHove - this is a record-triggered flow and I am making the users inactive by Salesforce's normal administration of users.